# SearchView is not responding in android

Tags: android, searchview

I want to implement searching in my application using SearchView .I am following  [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) tutorial.

I am having an activity which contains 3 tabs .On the toolbar ,i want to use searching .Screenshot is given below :

[image: Screenshot]

I have successfully added three tabs in my activity.Now to implement SearchView ,i am using the following code in my Activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_friend_list_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) FriendsListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            if (item != null) {
                searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
            }
            if (searchView != null) {
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(FriendsListActivity.this.getComponentName()));
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**menu_friend_list_activity.java**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

**searchable.xml under res/xml folder**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

**SearchResultActivity.java**

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Log.e("Query",query);
        //use the query to search your data somehow
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.FriendsListActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.WelcomeActivity">
            <!-- To display the search view-->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.SearchResultsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

On clicking the search icon ,Search view is displayed .But on entering the text,it should display the string entered in handleIntent() method.I am not able to receive ,what i am entering in search view.I might be possible that i am doing something wrong here.Please help me understand the working of SearchView.

Comment: `I want to implement searching in my application using SearchView` so what do you want to search for in your application?

Comment: @pskink : thanks for the reply . As you can see in the screenshot ,I have 3 tabs in my activity.One of the tab is displaying recent chat list.If i enter the name of user to which the chat has been already done it should be displayed.This is what i want.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e7HLF6X6

Comment: @pskink : I got the idea but the example you have given to me is applicable when i have listview inside a single activity.In my case list view is inside fragments.I have a ViewPager in my activity which is populated by fragments using FragmentStateAdapter.It means search view is on the toolbar which will search according to the tab opened by the user.

Comment: it is not important if it is inside an activity or fragment, it just works the same in both cases

Comment: @pskink : I have got the idea that when a user executes a search from the search view, the system starts your searchable activity and sends it a ACTION_SEARCH intent. This intent carries the search query in the QUERY string extra.  We need to check for this intent when the activity starts and extract the string.  I have used this code  if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.e("Query1",query);
            //use the query to search your data somehow
        }  But it is not printing anything.

Comment: did you see my code? does it work? did you see any ACTION_SEARCH in it?

Comment: @pskink : Also i got the idea that i need to check in the SearchableActivity that which tab is currently opened and need to filter the corresponding listview .Please tell me how can i perform this task

Comment: @pskink   Actually i have used SearchView in an activity which contains three tabs.ViewPager is used in this activity which is populated by Fragments using FragmentPagerAdapter.Please consider this scenario .

Comment: i have no idea what actually do you want to acheive... did you try my code? did it work?

Comment: @pskink : I want to implement search like WhatsApp.As you can see in WhatsApp we have an activity which contains search icon and 3 tabs namely Calls,Chats and Contacts .On clicking search i can search the contents of current tab.

Comment: and my code doesnt search (filter out) the content of the list view below? copy those 58 lines of code and just try...

Comment: @pskink : I have filtered the list view by using Filterable Interface in the base adapter.It is working for me . https://gist.github.com/DeepakRattan/26521c404ffd7071d0a4 is my implementation.But it works only when my searchview and my list view is in the same activity.

Comment: so use `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter`, it is even simpler than using `OnQueryTextListener` and calling `adapter.getFilter().filter()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107624/discussion-between-deepakr-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.FriendsListActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.WelcomeActivity">
        <!-- To display the search view-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SearchResultsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"
                android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

your **AndroidManifest.xml** change to below. If you have subfolder in your package, you have to set full package name in meta-data value.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.FriendsListActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.WelcomeActivity">
        <!-- To display the search view-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="your.package.name.activity.SearchResultsActivity" />

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SearchResultsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```